# Need help writing sql query in rails so I get ActiveRelation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need an active record relation that gives me the latest record of a region, city, bed combination. I have the sql query written as below, but I need to figure out if there is away to use a different approach to have it return an active record relation and not an array. Any suggestions?

Current query:

```
    @current_ltm_market_stats = LtmStatsByBedCount.find_by_sql(" SELECT *
          FROM ltm_stats_by_bed_counts lstats
          WHERE lstats.city_id = '#{@city_id}'
              #{@region_id_condition}
              AND (lstats.beds,lstats.city_id,lstats.region_id,lstats.reporting_date) 
            IN (SELECT lstats.beds,
                  lstats.city_id,
                  lstats.region_id,
                  max(lstats.reporting_date)
                                                          FROM ltm_stats_by_bed_counts lstats 
        WHERE lstats.city_id = '#{@city_id}'
         #{@region_id_condition}
         GROUP BY city_id, region_id, beds)
          ORDER BY lstats.year DESC,lstats.month DESC")
```

I had tried this before which did result in a relation but it runs really slowly and the result is not exactly the same. Are there any better rails ways to do this?

```
@all_ltm_market_stats = LtmStatsByBedCount.where(city_id: @market.city_id, region_id: @market.region_id)
        @current_ltm_market_stats = @latest_year_ltm_market_stats.where(month: @latest_year_ltm_market_stats.all_ltm_market_stats.select('Max(year)'))
```

Comment: Neither your first query has complete information, nor the second, there are variables values missing which i would need to work on it for you. Also table structures are a must too for such questions. Those make creating queries very easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Information in the question is incomplete, so i might have to update my answer when additional details are added*, 
But here is the initial draft with available information:

```
@current_ltm_market_stats = LtmStatsByBedCount.
  where(city_id: @city_id).
  where(@region_id_condition).
  where("(beds, city_id, region_id, reporting_date) IN (
    SELECT lstats.beds,
           lstats.city_id,
           lstats.region_id,
           max(lstats.reporting_date)
           FROM ltm_stats_by_bed_counts lstats 
           WHERE lstats.city_id = '#{@city_id}'
           #{@region_id_condition}
           GROUP BY city_id, region_id, beds)").
  order(year: :desc, month: :desc)
```

*Note that you might have to adjust your **`@region_id_condition`** a bit for this to work.*

Theoretically **it is equivalent of your SQL version(which means it will generate same sql excluding table alias) and returns the AR relation object**. Which is the only requirement in the question. Obviously SQL might be improved with additional information as well.

Additionally, you will want to have carefully crafted indexes on this table if you are going to use this query on larger datasets frequently.

Comment: Thanks Zia, I'll give that a shot. The region condition was for Nils, to make sure it wasn't making Nils = '' and gerefore affecting the results. This is on a view though so there is no index, but the view is limited to the most recent data so hopefully won't run into performance issues later.

Comment: That worked and was significantly faster than what I had before. It cut the response time in half (or faster). Thanks!